# react set state - unable to set key name with dot or bracket notation

Tags: reactjs

I am needing to setup state for a dynamic set of data. After the data loads, in the `ComponentDidUpdate` function I'm iterating through the dataset and then trying to `setState` for each item in state based on the items Id. I'm choosing id over index because the index isn't accessible once data is displayed and I won't be able to reference it.

When trying to set state I get an error in the IDE that the dot notation or the bracket notation is unexpected.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.props.report !== prevProps.report && this.props.report !== undefined){
      //set checkbox state dynamically for each row
      this.props.report.systemSourceList.forEach((item) =>
      this.setState((prevState) => ({selectedSourceRowIds : [...prevState.selectedSourceRowIds, {item['sourceId']: true}]}))
    }
}
```

I've tried both `item.sourceId` and `item['sourceId']` but neither work.

I also assigned item.sourceId to a variable and logged it to the console succesfully, but when I plug that variable into the keyName space the id of the source isn't used just `id`.

```
 this.props.report.systemSourceList.forEach((item) => {
        let id = item.sourceId;
        console.log(id);
         this.setState((prevState) => ({selectedSourceRowIds : [...prevState.selectedSourceRowIds, {id: true}]}))
      });
    }
```

The objects being looped through look like:

```
 { 
systemId: 13, 
facilityId: 4747, 
sourceId: "WS010", 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to go about this?

**UPDATE**

I got it - I needed to place brackets around the actual keyName. Final solution:

```
this.props.report.systemSourceList.forEach((item) => {
        let id = item.sourceId;
        console.log(id);
         this.setState((prevState) => ({selectedSourceRowIds : [...prevState.selectedSourceRowIds, {[id]: true}]}))
      });
```

Comment: Can you show an example data structure of an `item`?

Comment: I updated the OP to include this as well as other stuff I've tried